# IIS 7 - floats returning with commas instead of periods

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-7

I'm having trouble reading rows with float values, because these rows return for example 12,34 instead of 12.34 as it should.

I suspect this is because both my IIS and SQL server is on a Norwegian Windows Server 2008. So I went to the regional settings and customized the default decimal symbol, then restarted my servers. The output in the database now shows the period decimal symbol, but when I request it through the IIS server it comes comma separated (the IIS server is on another computer, but that also has the default decimal symbol set to period).

The IIS server is IIS7 and the SQL Server is 2008

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did a temporary fix by adding the following bit of code behind the float variables.


.ToString().Replace(',','.');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use to fetch the data from the database to IIS 7 (server side language)? I am guessing SQL Server is returning it right and the application is converting it to the right locale.

Comment: I'm using a controller from the asp.net mvc2 framework, as hosted on the IIS server, to retrieve the data from the mssql db on the other server.

Comment: It very likely has to do with your application locale.  I haven't used .NET in a while but these links might help out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204510/custom-culture-info-in-asp-net
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+cultureinfo
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/334.aspx