# Runtime Label Change?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, windows-runtime

What are the best practices on applying / changing control labels at runtime? For example, a customer's "Item Code" can be called "Item ID" or "Product Code" by another.  Unfortunately in our case, there is no set standard for what the entities are called, and there's quite a few of them.

We have been approaching it several ways (app config / custom configuration files / resource files) but we think there should be a framework that supports these kinds of customization without writing a lot of code.

Ideally, the changes can come from a custom file that can be deployed as part of the application build.  The runtime can pick it up and apply the changes automatically, just like resource strings.  Also, if a custom label is not available, it picks up the default.

Please note that this is not "localization" (everything is still en-US) but I'm not sure if this can be done via a pseudo-language as Tim Heuer describes here:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/04/26/localize-windows-8-application.aspx

Update:

This looks oddly similar to this question: [Custom Culture for client specific verbiage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059677/custom-culture-for-client-specific-verbiage)

The answer directs to a custom resource provider here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Is there a similar mechanism for the Windows Runtime?

Comment: just put your stuff in a text file, load the text via File.ReadAllText() and cache it and use a MarkupExtension to do your UI mapping. What have you tried / what is your question?

Comment: Are these hard coded labels or are they in a repeater control?  Please post a sample XAML of a label.